# jquery div on top of another div

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that contains a div element called #order_details that is hidden.  When a user clicks on a button, then the #order_details div element appears.  It appears that the div element has a z-index of 6500 which I have verified is the highest z-index in the entire site.  It is also using jQuery because I see code like:

```
$('#order_details').show();
```

which I know shows the #order_details div element.

```
<html>
    ...
    ...
    <div id="button"></div>
    <div id="order_details">

        <div id="button2launch_SURVEY"></div>
        <div id="survey">
        </div>

    </div>
</html>
```

Now I've added a new div element called #survey and when I click on a button in the #order_details div I want the survey to appear on the top.

I have set the z-index in the css #survey to be 6599.  Then I setup some jQuery to show the div.

```
$('#survey').show();
```

the #survey div appears, but it is not on top of the #order_details div.

My question is:

Isn't setting the z-index property of #survey to a higher value supposed to ensure that the #survey div will appear at the top?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you `#survey` has a positioning on `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`. [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)

Comment: stop the press!!!  I just tried absolute, and it appeared to work.  I thought I understood the difference between relative/absolute but I was obviously wrong.